# Is there any copy paste environment variable for cmd and powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, terminal, copy-paste

**Stage 1)** say I wanna do the following:

```
%cd% | > clip <
```

[To copy the current path I am in right now in my CMD shell session]

(**Useful info 1** I know the above code won't work as opposed to what it sounds like and to be more precise, it should be "CD | clip" to work that way, but lets assume for a second that there is an environment variable or something like a "%cd%" so that I can echo that or just a specific built-in command and whatsoever which can be used to output current working directory as a simple string (e.g "C:\Users\hello\there") to the std__exactly equivalent to what "pwd" in Unix-based operating systems does.)

**Stage 2)** And then I continue on to what follows:

```
cd | < clip >
```

[To paste what was copied on clipboard in stage 1]

(**Useful info 2** Although I don't care about cd's functioning in this example, you can just think of "cd" at the start of the command in stage 2 as the change-directory function and not a thing outputting current working directory)

> **Question:** What's the most similar default way of doing
> things like what is proposed in the example above, given that I'm not
> to use the Ctrl + Shift + V keyboard shortcut (say in windows terminal)?

I know how to do that in a Linux terminal but not in cmd shell. A little tip on that is more than appreciated:)

Comment: Well, in Windows, it would be *windows* + *v*. Anyways, in PowerShell, you can use the cmdlet `Get-Location` and pipe it to the `clip.exe` utility, or the `Set-Clipboard` cmdlet: `Get-Location | Set-Clipboard`, and using `clip.exe` would be, `Get-Location | clip`. This will allow you to *ctrl* + *v* seeing as it's now in your clipboard. There is also the *automatic* variable of `$pwd` which gives you the current location: `$pwd | scb`; (*scb being and alias to `Set-Clipboard`*). Is this what you're after?

Comment: `but lets assume for a second that there is an environment variable or something like a "%cd%"` - there literally is: `echo %cd%`

Comment: also consider looking into `pushd` and `popd` to go to a new location, and then return from where you came. Those may work for your purposes.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala thanks for mentioning the "scb" alias. it's really handy especially for those who think "Set-Clipboard" is too long to type.
by the way there is a problem with "get-location | clip". when you use this command (of course in powershell, you get an extra useless "Path----" at the start of your clipboard. I assume we can correct this behavior by doing "(get-location).path | clip" :P

Comment: What's missing in this question is what you're trying to do. Copying the current working directory to the clipboard is a means to an end, and your question does not talk about *what* end. You obviously don't actually want to use the clipboard, so the whole `clip.exe`/`Set-Clipboard` thing seems like a red herring.

Comment: @Tomalak well, suppose I'm running a terminal session, working on some project which is a good 5 directories deep down on my E:\ drive. All of a sudden I decide to open up another terminal session and navigate to my project. when starting a terminal session on windows, your starting path is probably "C:\Windows\System32" and you have to type the absolute path to navigate elsewhere, say in other drives. It would be a good idea to have a simple way of using commands to do that, right?

Comment: Yeah, for manually transferring a path between multiple sessions of `cmd` or `powershell`, using the clipboard would work. I was thinking more of an unattended script, where relying on the clipboard for literally *anything* would be asking for trouble.

Comment: ...although setting an environment variable (e.g. `setx MY_LAST_DIR %cd% > NUL`) and using an alias for `cd "%MY_LAST_DIR%`" (or a startup script) in your new session would probably be better, since destroying the clipboard content is always extremely unelegant.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I can do in powershell:

**Stage 1:** copying the current path:

```
(pwd).path | scb
```

**useful info:**

- scb is an alias for "Set-Clipboard".
- The parenthesis in "(pwd)" is mandatory since we are running a pwd command within our whole command.
- ".path" is used to get the path as a simple string. Remember pwd in powershell outputs "Path----- C:\current\path". We only want the path and not the "Path------" part, so we have to use ".path". I hope it's clear.

**Stage 2:** going back one directory (only for demonstration purpose):

```
cd ..
```

**Stage 3:** reverting to the path copied in stage 1 (or even in another terminal session):

```
cd (gcb)
```

**useful info**

- gcb is an alias for "Get-Clipboard".
- Again parenthesis matters. In another words, "cd gcb" does NOT work.

PS: I think we can make a batch for that. for instance when starting a new terminal session, we won't have to type the complete path to navigate to the working directory in previous session.
By the way, it still is a powershell method. I'd appreciate if someone could show me a similar way in pure cmd__if there is any.

Comment: You'd have to ask a new question. Making threads of new question as answers posts isn't allowed. Also, wanted to say, using `$pwd.Path` you don't have to place it in a grouping operator `(..)`; since it's and automatic variable.  It should also not output the property name just the value: `$pwd | scb` will work.

Comment: *"Remember pwd in powershell outputs `"Path----- C:\current\path"`."* - No, it doesn't. It outputs an object with a `.Path` property, and a couple others, like `.Drive` or `.Provider`. Only if you coerce it into a string indiscriminately (e.g. by putting it into the clipboard) it loses its structure and becomes a visual representation of that object.